# MQTT messageId practical implementation

Tags: mqtt

The company I am working for has evaluated MQTT and decided to use it as a core messaging platform for a large scale system. The main reason is how compact the protocol is and how easy it can actually be implemented. I have a single issue with MQTT though and I'm seeking for an answer to the following question:

QoS1 and QoS2 messages require confirmation from the client. The only thing I know about the message (identifying it) when receiving PUBACK, PUBREC, PUBREL and PUBCOMP is messageId and the clientId. Message id is an unsigned int16 so the max value is 65535. It doesn't seem to be large enough for long running clients, say a year, sending 15 QoS2 messages an hour.

I am not quite sure if there's any other way to identify the message? I would like to be as compliant with the standard as possible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably the first point to make clear is that message IDs are handled on a per client and per direction basis. That is to say that the broker will create a message ID for each outgoing message with QoS>0 for each client that is connected and these message IDs will be completely independent of any other message IDs used for the same message published to other clients. Likewise, each client generates its own message IDs for messages that it sends.

The message ID doesn't have to be unique, so your client sending 15 messages per hour with QoS level 2 would simply overflow at some point. The real limitation is that there can only be a maximum of 65535 messages per direction "in flight" at once (i.e. part way through the message handshake). Once a message with a given ID has been fully processed then that message ID can be reused.

Another way of looking at it is to consider how it would work if your client only ever had one message in flight at once, whether because of the rate the messages are being transmitted or by design in the way you handle the messages. In this case, you could keep message ID set to 1 for every single message because there is never a chance that there will be a duplicate.

If you wish to support having multiple messages in flight at once it would be relatively straightforward to check there are no message ID duplicates before you assign a new one.

Because the message ID is per client, if you send a single message to >65535 clients there will be no chance of message ID collisions. If you send >65535 messages to each client at once and the message flows aren't complete then there will be problems.

Answering the comment "I have noticed that every MQTT broker tends to deliver only the last QoS1/2 message":

The broker will only send messages to clients it knows about. If you connect for the first time there is no way to get messages from the past, with one exception: retained messages. If a message is set to retained then it is a "last known good" value. When a new client subscribes it will be sent the retained message immediately which makes it useful for things that are updated infrequently. I suspect this is what you are referring to. If you want a client to have messages queued when it is not connected then you must connect with the "clean session" option disabled to make the client persistent. You must also use QoS>0 subscriptions and QoS>0 publications. When your client reconnects (with clean session still set to disabled), the queued messages will be delivered. You can normally configure the number of messages to queue in this way in the broker, where any further messages will be discarded. An important point is that queueing messages for a client that has not previously connected is not supported by design.

Comment: I understand this point, thank you for the answer by the way.
I have noticed that every MQTT broker tends to deliver only the last QoS1/2 message. What if I'd like to deliver more? What is there is more than 65535? I do understand that this is highly unlikely but it is possible.
The solution you suggest is good for a known number of recipients. The situation I am dealing with is that I do not know how many recipients there may be and are they still in the factory. Basically, they could be there but never come in. And there may be hundrers of thousands of them.

Comment: One point that I'd not made clear is that the message ID is per client and per direction. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: I've also answered your other point. If that doesn't clear things up please leave another comment.

Comment: Actually, one more, when broker republishes the message on behalf of another client, should I be changing the message id? From your earlier explanation it seems like this is the case.

Comment: Yes, that's the key point I was trying to get across. You should maintain an incoming and and outgoing message id per client.

Answer (score 0):

For delivering more messages at QOS1 or QOS2, you should use concept of persistant memory. In this when ever a subscriber is not available the message get stored in persistant memory and deliver once subscriber is connected. You can do this at QOS0 also after configuring mosquitto.conf file.